# Linear Transformation applied to the some of the basis of P3

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_3 \rightarrow P_3$ be a linear transformation such that $T(-2x^2) = (-3x^2 -4x)\\ T(-0.5x+3) = (-2x^2 -2x -4)\\ T(5x^2 +1) = (-2x-4).\\$

Find $T(1), T(x), T(x^2) and T(ax^2+bx+c)$ where a,b,c are arbitrary real numbers.

I sort of know what to do, but getting very confused.

So I put these in a matrix
$3 \times 3$~matrix
[ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -0.5 & 3 \\
5 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)]$

and was going to row reduce so I can find an a, b and c such that $1 = a(-2x^2) +b(-0.5x+3) +c(5x^2+1)$ but I'm not quite getting there (I can row reduce but I'm getting the wrong answer, therefore I know something in my set up is wrong) Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Guidance**

This problem has an answer if the set $(-2x^2,0.5x+3,5x^2+1)$ is a basis of $P_3$ *(and this is the case, prove it!)* and so we can express the polynomials $1,x$ and $x^2$ relative to this basis. Now use that $T$ is linear transformation to find $T(1),T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to write 1 for example relative to this basis

Comment: SORRY GUYS, IT'S OK I FIGURED IT OUT THANKS